# Customizing jaxb bindings for primtive

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I have several schemas I am generating jaxb bindings for that make liberal use of `xs:integer`.  I wish to have these values bound to `long`/`Long` rather than the default BigInteger.  Unfortunately I do not have the ability to modify the schemas.  Adding a simple declaration to my bindings file causes `xs:integer` to be bound to `Long` in all cases, even when it's a required value:

```
<jaxb:javaType xmlType="xs:integer" name="long" />
```

How can I get `xs:integer` to be bound to a primitive when the field is required?

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty simple you just need to have two different bindings in your `.jxb` file and use correct XPath selector to find the elements which need to be mapped to `Integer` and another XPath selector which will find elements which are going to be mapped to `int`.

As you have not posted your `.xsd` and `.xjb` files, I will just show on a small example how things are working. Let's assume we have following `.xsd` file

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="user">
         <xs:complexType>
             <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="age" minOccurs="1"/>
                 <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="balance" minOccurs="0"/>
             </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

So from the `.xsd` we can see that we have a definition of `user` object which has `age` property which is required (still we could use use="optional" attribute as well, but that does not matter) and the `balance` property which is optional.

So lets say we want the `age` to be mapped to Java `int` and the `balance` to `Integer`.

So we just need a binding file which will find all the nodes which have `type` attribute equal to `xs:integer` and `minOccurs` attribute equal to 1 and apply some custom mapping rule and do the same for all the ones with `minOccurs` attribute equal to 0.

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.0" 
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
        <!---Find all optional integers and map them to java.lang.Integer -->
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@minOccurs='0' and @type='xs:integer']" multiple="true">
            <xjc:javaType name="java.lang.Integer" adapter="adapters.IntegerAdapter" />
        </jxb:bindings>

        <!---Find all required integers and map them to primitive int -->
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@minOccurs='1' and @type='xs:integer']" multiple="true">
            <xjc:javaType name="int" adapter="adapters.IntAdapter" />
        </jxb:bindings>

    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

That's it after running the build (remember to enable vendor customization be adding `-extension` command line argument) you will have something like this.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"age",
"balance"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User {

    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IntAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "integer")
    protected int age;
    @XmlElement(type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IntegerAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "integer")
    protected Integer balance;

    // getters setters will be here
}
```

Also, note that I'm not adding the sources for `adapters.IntegerAdapter` and `adapters.IntAdapter` this part is for you )

Comment: This only partly worked for me. The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` was not able to match the primitive to the generics of the `IntAdapter` and I needed to add an explicit typemapping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70758244/jaxb-not-adding-primitive-type-to-xmljavatypeadapter-annotation