# JAXB not adding primitive type to @XMLJavaTypeAdapter annotation

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I have been given an XSD which contains a `xs:integer` field. I want the generated code to use an `int`, so I can apply an existing interface to it. (the field is required and will never exceed the 32-bit range, it should have been an `xs:int`).

Using XJB I can change the type in the generated code. But this gives me an error when creating a `JAXBContext`.

```xml
<bindings
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
  <bindings schemaLocation="mySchema.xsd">
    <bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='myField']">

      <!-- either with jaxb -->
      <property name="myField">
        <baseType name="int">
          <javaType name="int" />
        </baseType>
      </property>

      <!-- or with xjc-->
      <xjc:javaType name="int"/>

    </bindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

this generates the following code

```java
public class MyClass {
    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = Adapter1.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "integer")
    protected int myField;

    // ...
}
```

While this works for code-generation, it fails for marshalling and throws the following exception when creating a context.

```plaintext
Adapter myPackage.Adapter1.class is not applicable to the field type int. 
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter$DEFAULT.class, value=mySchemaPackage.Adapter1.class)
```

if I manually add a type-parameter to the annotation the problem is solved, but I cannot find a way to make JAXB do this for me.

```java
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = Adapter1.class, type = int.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [JAXB2-Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics)-plugin I managed to override the generated annotation. I decided to use a named adapter instead of the dynamically generated `Adapter1.class`, but the implementation of `IntAdapter` is the same `XmlAdapter<String, Integer>` as JAXB would generate.

```xml
<bindings
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net">
  <bindings schemaLocation="mySchema.xsd">
    <bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='myField']">

      <annox:annotate target="field">
        @javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=myCodePackage.IntAdapter.class, type=int.class)
      </annox:annotate>
      <xjc:javaType name="int" adapter="myCodePackage.IntAdapter"/>

    </bindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

and now the code is generated like

```java
@XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = IntAdapter.class, type = int.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "integer")
protected int myField;
```